# Textarea value update not reflect in page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update a textarea's value with Javascript. The code is similar to:

```
console.warn("Before set, value is " + document.getElementById('myTextArea').value);
document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = 'OMGWTFBBQ';
console.warn("After set, value is " + document.getElementById('myTextArea').value);
```

Although the Firefox and Chrome consoles show that the `value` property is updated, this is not reflected in the page itself.

The specific function is invoked from an `onfocus` handler of another element. The textarea itself is lazily initialised from the same method, by using:

```
var messageText = document.createElement('textarea');
messageText.id = 'myTextArea';
someParent.appendChild(messageText);
```

Obviously if I use the console rather than let the script run it does work.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, here is the closest I could emulate and it's working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/QRjyH/ so please give more details, I would start with the full code that create the `textarea`. One important thing to note: you must not have more than one element with same ID, so if you create new textarea each time you focus something and give it the same ID it can explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm after some testing, seems it should work like you want it to, so not sure why it doesn't, you can try to use the following instead though and see if it solves your problem:

```
console.warn("Before set, value is " + document.getElementById('myTextArea').value);
document.getElementById('myTextArea').firstChild.textContent = 'OMGWTFBBQ';
console.warn("After set, value is " + document.getElementById('myTextArea').value);
```

If this doesn't work for you either, then something about your page is very strange :)

Try something extremely simple like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
console.warn("Before set, value is " + document.getElementById('myTextArea').value);
document.getElementById('myTextArea').firstChild.textContent = 'OMGWTFBBQ';
console.warn("After set, value is " + document.getElementById('myTextArea').value);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="myTextArea">hey</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

if this works, then the browser is not at fault, and you need to find the problem in your code. If this doesn't work, you can blame the browser :)

Comment: Was just trying your first suggestion with no results. I tried accessing the `firstChild`, but it is `null`...

Comment: ok the above solution (and your own) works in firefox 3.6/chromium 8, so something must be broken in the builds you are playing with

Comment: Yes, something about my page is strange. I manually created a textNode child, but calls to firstChild.textContent don't change the page either.

Comment: Marking as the correct answer since it helped me track down the root cause. Another part of the script was overwriting the value. Cost me a couple of hours to find.